# Why aren't my websites configured in IIS using the correct certificates?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, ssl-certificate, certificate

My sites are similarly named:

- hi.api.domain.tld
- hi.test.domain.tld

The `.api` domain is my api and `.test` is the webapp that consumes the api.

I've got a certificate for each one but they don't seem to be working right.

One of them works fine:

> Certificate Name matches hi.test.
> Subject hi.test.redacted

The other one, however, seems to be using this same certificate (hi.test) for the hi.api site according to digicert:

> Certificate does not match name hi.api.
> Subject   hi.test.redacted

The reason why is a mystery to me because the certificate I've configured for use on the `hi.api` site is, in fact, the one for hi.api (see image below).

I'm really not a server guy so I can't even guess at the cause or how to fix. I'm not even sure what to google to find an answer here so if anyone has any insight or can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#sni-based-bindings If you don't set SNI based mappings, then nothing will work. There is already an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to verify the Subject and/or Subject Alternative Name match the URL. The name of the certificate itself doesn't mean anything. The error is stating the Subject CN doesn't match the site name.

If you look in the Details tab:

1. Look at 'Subject' for the CN (example on stackexchange: CN = *.stackexchange.com)
2. Look at the 'Subject Alternative Name' Example below

   ```
    DNS Name=*.askubuntu.com
    DNS Name=*.blogoverflow.com
    DNS Name=*.mathoverflow.net
    DNS Name=*.meta.stackexchange.com
    ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both sites are on the same interface, you'll want to check the box for "Require Server Name Indication" so that the hostnames are presented and the appropriate SSL certificate can be presented.